# Django trying use apache2 mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I want use django on my ubuntu localhost with apache 2.4. I installed mod_wsgi using
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi

I want point my app written in django

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/wiersze.td.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName  wiersze.td
#DocumentRoot /
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/s/py/django/kitty/kitty/wsgi.py
Alias / /home/s/py/django/kitty/kitty/
Alias /adminmedia/  /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
<Directory "/home/s/py/django/kitty/kitty/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after enable my site and added hosts I see my files inside kitty directory. Why I cant see my index view?

Comment: i dont see index view but whole directory content

Answer (score 2):

I think there is problem with alias. Remove following line, restart Apache and retry browsing your site:

```
Alias / /home/s/py/django/kitty/kitty/
```

Thanks

Comment: Correct. The Alias for '/' overrides WSGIScriptAlias for '/'. See the documentation http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files